# react js VS next14

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frameworks

i am a developer and i created a to much complex project in react js with ts and i also have 2nd part as a backend and 3rd is socket server so i use firebase in frontand and in backend mongoDB and firebase admin

my project so messy i'm not able to maintain folder structure so i decided to rebuild this app because in future it becomes bigger.

so my issue is that which framework i should I use? react or go with next 14?
i also have to maintain 2 more servers that work with. express js and 3rd is socket server. what should i do i have time to change everything!

**React vs. Next.js 14**:

React:

Pros:

- Simpler learning curve if you're already familiar with React.
- Greater flexibility and control over your codebase.
- Lighter weight, may be better for smaller projects.

Cons:

- Requires manual configuration for routing, data fetching, SEO, etc.
- - More boilerplate code, especially for complex projects.
    Might be difficult to maintain scalability and code organization for your size project.

Next.js 14:

Pros:

- Built on top of React, leveraging its strengths.
- Offers built-in features for routing, data fetching, SEO, server-side rendering, and static site generation.
- Simplifies project structure and organization with conventions and automatic optimizations.
- Offers server-side components for more efficient data fetching and code splitting.

Cons:

- Slightly steeper learning curve than pure React.
- Less flexibility than pure React, as it enforces certain conventions.
- Slightly larger initial bundle size.

Comment: The React Core Team themselves recommend using a framework https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project

Answer (score 0):

You can go with either but even reactjs doc suggest NEXTJS Or Remix

And using nextjs you might be able to complete your project faster, since it comes with more configs

Comment: hmm i think next14 is choice. but i also want to maintain my 2 more servers!

Comment: @rutvikMovaliya you will be able to do the same thing with nextjs too